# How to query data that is ommitted from the results

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

So I have the following information

### Output

```
Diabetic    Schools   studentcount
false        9010         180
true         9010           3
false        9012         245
true         9012           4
```

### Query

```
Select s.diabetic as diabetic, sch.buildingid as Schools, 
       count(distinct s.studentnmr) as Studentcount
from student s
inner join studentschool ss.studentid = s.studentid
inner join school sch.id = ss.schoolid
order by sch.id
```

### I want

```
Diabetic    addresse    studentcount    calculation
true           9010           3             1,64 %
true           9012           4             1,61 %
```

where calculation is

```
( sum(diabetic=true)/sum(total number of students of the school) )*100
```

Additional tip there is another field called

```
 diabeticdate
```

which has a date when diabetic is true.

### My problem

when I select

```
select sum(Case when s.diabetic is null then 1 else 0 end) AS notD
```

I get obviously nothing next to the record diabetic - True status

How do I work around this

note: if you have a better title for the question, please suggest!

Comment: Maybe make 2 seperate ctes...?! I think that solves part of it

Comment: Why `count(distinct s.studentnmr)`? Can the same student appear twice in `studentschool`? If so, why? How does `diabeticdate` come into play? Do you want to use it? Do you want the diabetics rate for a certain date other than today?

Comment: diabeticdate only has a record is diabetic is true. in other when diabeticdate is null means the student is not diabetic. I dont want anything do with dates simply that its there

Comment: im counting distinct number of students so i cant count number of people who are diabetic

Comment: So we can ignore that date, because we see whether a student is diabetic from `s.diabetic` already. As to distinct counting: What is the difference between counting students in the school and distinct students in the school? Shouldn't this be the same number? Or does the table `studentschool` contain duplicates, i.e. multiple records per student?

Comment: yes contains duplicates in some instances which is why distinct is applied

Comment: e.g. student still entering our school, gets a temp id until he passes the entrance exam, then gets assigned with everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation in order to show one row per school with their diabetic rates:

```
select
  sch.buildingid as Schools, 
  count(distinct s.studentnmr) as Studentcount
  count(distinct case when s.diabetic then s.studentnmr end) as Diabeticcount,
  count(distinct case when s.diabetic then s.studentnmr end) /
    count(distinct s.studentnmr) * 100 as rate
from student s
inner join studentschool on ss.studentid = s.studentid
inner join school on sch.id = ss.schoolid
group by sch.buildingid
having count(distinct case when s.diabetic then s.studentnmr end) > 0
order by sch.buildingid;
```

Remove the `HAVING` clause, if you also want to see schools without diabetics.

Comment: If you want to show it, add `true as diabetic` to your select clause :-)

Comment: im soo confused, everythign worked but the case statements u wrote. I cant understand it. then s.studentnmr what does this operation even mean? why not then 1 else 0 for example?

Answer (score 1):

you may try below by using over()

```
  with t1 as
    (
    Select s.diabetic as diabetic, sch.buildingid as Schools, 
           count(distinct s.studentnmr) as Studentcount
    from student s
    inner join studentschool ss.studentid = s.studentid
    inner join school sch.id = ss.schoolid
    order by sch.id

    ),
t2 as
(
select case when Diabetic='true' then Schools end as addresse,
case when when Diabetic='true' then studentcount end as studentcount,
((case when when Diabetic='true' then studentcount end)::decimal/(sum(studentcount) over())) *100 as calculation
) select * from t2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window function `SUM OVER` to get the total number of students. Window functions run over the results you already have, a post aggregation so to say :-)

```
select
  s.diabetic as diabetic,
  sch.buildingid as Schools, 
  count(distinct s.studentnmr) as Studentcount,
  count(distinct s.studentnmr)::decimal / 
    sum(count(distinct s.studentnmr)) over (partition by sch.buildingid) * 100 as rate
from student s
inner join studentschool on ss.studentid = s.studentid
inner join school on sch.id = ss.schoolid
group by sch.buildingid, s.diabetic
order by sch.buildingid, s.diabetic;
```

Comment: So i got the calcuation i needed, now I need to hide results that have false. When i used having s.diabetic = true the calculation was wrong. What you suggest?

Comment: Ah, you don't want to show both rows. I'll post another answer on this.